# How to solve congruence $x^y = a \pmod p$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

I'm having trouble solving this congruence:
$$x^{114} \equiv 13 \pmod {29}.$$
I thought that it made sense to try to solve it using this idea: "Suppose you want to solve the congruence $ x^y \equiv a \pmod p$ (we will assume for the moment
that $p$ is prime). Raise both sides to the power $z$ to obtain $x^{yz} \equiv a^z
\pmod p$. Now if we can
ﬁnd a $z $ such that $yz \equiv 1 \pmod {p − 1}$ then the solution of the congruence will be $x \equiv a^z \pmod p$."

So I set $114 z \equiv 1 \pmod {28}$. However, $\gcd(114, 28) = 2$ and I can't solve for the inverse using the Euclidean algorithm. Does that statement that I quoted even come in handy anywhere?

Next I simplified $x^{114}$ to $x^2$ by Fermat's theorem.

I know that $x^2 \equiv 13 \pmod {29}$ has a solution because of the Legendre symbol:
$$\left(\frac{13}{29}\right) \equiv 13^{14} \pmod {29} = 1$$

The only way I have learned to solve for square roots is when $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. Since this isn't the case, I'm at a loss as to how to find the square root. Any tips or hints?

Comment: Tonelli-Shanks or Cipolla algorithm in general. Here one just knows that $10^2 = 100 \equiv 13 \pmod{29}$, so $x \equiv \pm10 \pmod{29}$.

Comment: What does that $=1$ mean near the end?

Comment: It's the Legendre symbol. If $(\frac ap) = +1$, then $x^2 = a (mod p)$ has a solution, and does not have a solution if = -1

Comment: The notation looks very strange. If you mean $\left(\frac a p\right)=1$, why is that all mixed up with a congruence?

Comment: @dfeuer It is a theorem that $$\left(\frac{n}p\right)\equiv n^{\frac{p-1}2}\mod p$$

Comment: Once you have found a square root $x$ of $13$, you can use your idea to find the unique $y$ such that $y^{57}\equiv x\pmod{29}$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, I'm only asking about the notation in $\left({13\over29}\right)\equiv13^{14}\pmod{29}=1$.

Comment: What if I had not been able to simplify it to $x^2$ and it was simplified to $x^4$ or a bigger exponent. Would I still be able to solve it then?

Comment: @DanielFischer, How did you just know that $x = 10$. Is it really just common knowledge? Can I ask what your thought process was?

Comment: The part $10^2 = 100$ is common knowledge. That $100 = 87+13 = 3\cdot 29 + 13$ is something turning up often enough when doing computations by hand that it's stored in my L2-cache, like the small powers of $2$ or the small squares. A happy coincidence. I wouldn't have seen that the square roots of $5$ modulo $29$ are $\pm 11$ immediately, that would have required a bit of mental arithmetic.

Comment: Alternately, note that $2$ is a primitive root $\pmod{29}$, so we can write $x^{114}$ as $2^{114k}$ for some $k\in\mathbf{Z}$. Now, suppose we know the $c\in\mathbf{Z}^{+}$ such that $2^c\equiv 13\pmod{29}$. Then, using the fact that $a^r\equiv a^s\pmod{m}\iff r\equiv s\pmod{\varphi(m)}$, we get the congruence $114k\equiv c\pmod{\varphi(29)}$, or $114k\equiv c\pmod{29}$, which is _much_ easier to solve. Admittedly, this solution is not the best since finding the discrete logarithm $c$ is annoying, but if $c$ is given this is an easy way to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my intuitive solution:
$$x^{114} \equiv 13 \pmod {29}$$
As shown above by the Fermat Little Theorem, the congruence is simplified to
$$x^{2} \equiv 13 \pmod {29}$$
Now we subtract $29$ from the right hand side of the congruence
$$x^{2} \equiv -16 \pmod {29}$$
We can notice that $-16=4*(-4)$, so we can say
$$4 \equiv 4 \pmod {29}$$
$$29-4 \equiv 25 \equiv -4 \pmod {29}$$
Now we multiply the last two congrunces
$$100 \equiv -16 \equiv 13 \pmod {29}$$
100 is a perfect square, thus the solution is $x=10$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, reduce the exponent immediately $\mod 28$ using Fermat's Theorem. So now you have to solve $x^2 = 13 \mod 29$ and since $13^{14} = 1 \mod 29$ you know there is a solution - actually there are two, namely $x$ and $29 - x$.

To find a solution in this simple case, just do a complete search up to $x = 14$. The result is $x = 10$. Anything else is a waste of time.

Now if you had to find $x$ such that
$$
x^{3000000000000000000350} = 345679012320987652917 \mod 1000000000000000000117
$$
that would be a different matter. That's also a problem of the form "solve $x^2 = a \mod p$ and $p = 1 \mod 4$." In that case use the algorithm proposed by Daniel Fisher. It's built into Mathematica.